# JavaFx : Playing list of media files with pause in between

Tags: mp3, media-player, javafx, javafx-2, playlist

I am trying to play a list of mp3 files in JavaFx and need to pause for few seconds in between each file.This question may be subjective but I am unable to find any technique to get handle of another JavaFx MediaPlayer object at the end of currently playing mediaPlayer, which is being played inside a runnable object.

Any code sample/Algorithm will be a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list of mediaPlayers, iterate through the list and for each mediaPlayer:

1. Call mediaPlayer.[setonEndofMedia](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnEndOfMedia%28java.lang.Runnable%29).
2. In your end of media Runnable create a [PauseTransition](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) for the duration you want to pause.
3. Supply a [setOnFinished](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#setOnFinished%28javafx.event.EventHandler%29) event handler for the pause transition which starts the next MediaPlayer in the list.

Comment: Thanks I used the following code  
PauseTransition pt = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(2000));
                    pt.play();
                    pt.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                            if (mediaPlayer3 != null) {
                                mediaPlayer3.play();
                            }
                        }
                    });

Answer (score 1):

Turn [`@SoulMan`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/747456/soulman)'s comment into answer:

---

Thanks I used the following code:

```
PauseTransition pt = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(2000));
pt.play();
pt.setOnFinished(
    new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
         if (mediaPlayer3 != null) {
             mediaPlayer3.play();
         }
      }
});
```